# Centering contour plot cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy, netcdf4

I'm trying centralize my plot over the pacific ocean.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy, cartopy.crs as ccrs

url = 'https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/pub/sod/mecb/crw/data/5km/v3.1_op/nc/v1.0/daily/ssta/2023/ct5km_ssta_v3.1_20230101.nc#mode=bytes'
file = Dataset(url)
data = file.variables['sea_surface_temperature_anomaly'][:][0]
lat = file.variables['lat'][:]
lon = file.variables['lon'][:]
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
limites =[-180, 180, -90, 90]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m', color='black')
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, edgecolor='black')
ax.set_extent(limites, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
cf = plt.contourf(xi, yi, data, 
                  extent=limites, 
                  origin='upper'
                  )
```

This is the result:
[image]

I tried using ccrs.PlateCarree(), but this happens:

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
```

[image]

My expected plot is something like this ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By changing the map projection using a different central longitude, you change the meaning (physical location) of the coordinates. With a central longitude of lon=0°, that coordinate is located at the Greenwhich meridian, while with a central longitude of 180° that same value (lon=0°) is located at the International Date Line.

Changing the map projection like that is fine of course, but you have to also change the coordinates of the data you provide (which still has the definition of central longitude=0). Or when using Matplotlib/Cartopy, provide the correct transformation need to do it on-the-fly (with `transform=...`).

If you specifically need Matplotlib's `contourf`, which requires monotonically increasing coordinates, the easiest in this specific case is probably to just modify the data array by rolling it half the width like:

```py
data = np.roll(data, lon.size//2, axis=1)
```

The above is a little tricky, but works in this case because the difference between both projections is just a shift along the horizontal axis.

Note that the use of both `xi`, `yi` AND `extent=` is redundant, it's either one or the other. When providing the x/y coordinates like this, they can remain 1D (no need for manually using `np.meshgrid`). So I would just pass the lon/lat arrays as they are.

For example:

```py
map_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(10, 5), layout="compressed", facecolor="w", dpi=100,
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_proj),
)

ax.coastlines(resolution='110m', color='k', lw=.5, alpha=.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, ec='k', lw=.5, alpha=.5)

im = ax.contourf(
    lon, lat, data, origin='upper', cmap="RdBu_r", 
    levels=np.arange(-3,3.1,0.5), extend="both",
    transform=map_proj,
)

cb = fig.colorbar(im, shrink=.5)
```

Results in:
[image]

If you don't specifically need `contourf` you could also consider `pcolormesh`, which gives a very similar result. With the settings below it results in a continuous color gradient, but you could provide a `BoundaryNorm` for similar discrete colors as the `contourf` method.

The `pcolormesh` method can use the original data (without `np.roll`) as long as you also provide the original projection, Cartopy will correctly handle the transformation on-the-fly.

Using `pcolormesh` is much more flexible regarding the input data, it for example doesn't require the assumption of a regular grid. So it can also be useful for debugging in a case like this. The flexibility does require a lot more complicated interpolation under the hood, so there's a performance penalty that's noticeable on large grids like this.

```py
map_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(10, 5), layout="compressed", facecolor="w", dpi=100,
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_proj),
)

ax.coastlines(resolution='110m', color='k', lw=.5, alpha=.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, ec='k', lw=.5, alpha=.5)

im = ax.pcolormesh(

    lon, lat, data, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), 
    vmin=-3, vmax=3, cmap="RdBu_r",
)
cb = fig.colorbar(im, shrink=.5, extend="both")
```

[image]

That last example can now for example be quickly changed to using an equal area projection by changing the map projection to for example:

```py
map_proj = ccrs.EqualEarth(central_longitude=180)
```

[image]

The on-the-fly reprojection for that last example will be even slower, but it's very easy/convenient. Better performance could probably be gained by doing the reprojection upfront with something like `gdalwarp`. The data also likely has a higher resolution (7200x3600) compared to your final image, reducing the size before plotting with Matplotlib also speeds things up a little.